# Stopping the menu icon flicker

Tags: gnome, flicker

Every time I click on the application or system menus, I notice that no icons show up for a second, then they page in. Is there some way to explicitly tell Ubuntu to cache this? My SuSE (GNOME) desktop doesn't have this problem, but I don't know whether that's because they're doing something custom, or because it's a setting I'm missing.

Comment: You will be glad to know that this issue will be fixed in the next version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to manually tell Ubuntu to [update the icon cache](http://www.marksanborn.net/linux/speed-up-the-gnome-menu-and-fix-the-annoying-icon-delay/). This command should accomplish that for you:

```
gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/THEMENAME/
```

Replacing `THEMENAME` with your theme name, of course.